# How to turn equation with decrementing indexing into math equation with summation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, equation

Similar to this question: [Turn while loop into math equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392375/turn-while-loop-into-math-equation?rq=1), I have the following nested loop that I am trying to convert into a math equation as I need to write this up in a format that doesn't look like code. I believe I am going to need some type of summation equation.

Here is the code:

```
int num = 0;
for (int i = nr - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = nc - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        ela[i][j] = num;
        eha[i][j] = num + ea[i][j] - 1;
        num += ea[i][j];                    
    }
}
```

I know that summations start from a lower bound and continue to a higher bound, so I'm not quite sure how to apply a summation here since I start from a higher index and continue to a lower index.

I'm not sure why I'm getting downvoted, as the question I referenced is very similar to mine, has the same tags and is upvoted 14 times. Please comment below if I can improve my question somehow.

**Update:**

I was able to update the formula as follows:

```
nr = 50;
nc = 10;

num = sum[ea[i,j],i=0,nr-1,j=0,nc-1]; // correct based upon nr, nc and ea
for (int i = 0; i < nr; i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nc; j++) {
        num = num - ea[i,j];
        ela[i][j] = num;
        eha[i][j] = num + ea[i,j] - 1;                              
    }
}
```

Comment: What for is `ELA` and `EHA` important here? What is `ea`?

Comment: @LogicStuff I think those are what he would like to express as functions.

Comment: @LogicStuff, ela and eha are variables that are set by this loop.

Comment: Somehow I feel this is off topic here.

Comment: The [background question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230743/how-to-turn-for-loop-into-a-math-equation)

Comment: @LogicStuff, ea is a variable

Comment: Who cares which way the index is going if you don't modify `ea`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The `way the index is going` matters because of `num` which is a *reverse* partial sum.

Comment: So `ea` is a scalar now, no longer an array? This changes the question altogether. It's generally better advised to make up your mind *before* posting.

Comment: @dxiv,  I modified it to simplify the problem. I didn't change my mind. apologies for any confusion this may have caused you. I'll revert it back for you.

Comment: @Veridian Was just pointing out that it's a quite different problem if all `ea[i][j]` have the same value. For one example, `num` can be calculated directly from `i, j` in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right, you can transcribe the effect as

[image]

You can describe this as the matrix `ela` being a *2D suffix sum* of the matrix `ea` (for every element, sum of the elements that follow in the lexicographical ordering), while `eha` is the sum of matrices `ela` and `ea` minus all ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just with how to express the sum when you're looping the other direction, you can change your code to:

```
int num = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nc; j++) {
        ela[nr - i][nc - j] = num;
        eha[nr - i][nc - i] = num + ea[nr - i][nc - j] - 1;
        num += ea[nr - i][nc - j];                    
    }
}
```

I'm not saying you have to change your code to this, but from here it should be more obvious how to change this to use summation notation.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to tell without any context, but the code in question becomes more intelligible if you think of the arrays as vectors enumerating the elements in reverse order, row-major. The code below is functionally equivalent to the original one posted, but arguably easier to follow.

```
// n.b. ela[nr - 1 - i][nc - 1 - j] == rela(nc * i + j);
int &rela(int k) { return ela[nr - 1 - k / nc][nc - 1 - k % nc]; }
int &reha(int k) { return elh[nr - 1 - k / nc][nc - 1 - k % nc]; }
int &rea(int k)  { return  ea[nr - 1 - k / nc][nc - 1 - k % nc]; }

for (int k = 0, sum = 0; k < nr * nc - 1; k++) {
    rela(k) = sum;
    sum += rea(k);
    reha(k) = sum - 1;
}
```

In plain English, `rela(k)` is the partial sum of `rea` elements `0 ... k-1` and `reha(k)` is one less than the partial sum of `rea` elements `0 ... k` (also, `rela(k) == reha(k - 1) + 1` for `k > 0`).

Technically, this description could be translated back in terms of the 2d arrays, but it becomes rather messy quickly.